# NSMutableArray with multiple properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a rather large NSMutableArray with class files. The array has multiple properties like so:

```
[Element elementsName:@"Lithium" elementsNumber:@"3"],
[Element elementsName:@"Beryllium" elementsNumber:@"4"],
[Element elementsName:@"Boron" elementsNumber:@"5"],
[Element elementsName:@"Carbon" elementsNumber:@"6"],
[Element elementsName:@"Nitrogen" elementsNumber:@"7"],
[Element elementsName:@"Oxygen" elementsNumber:@"8"],
[Element elementsName:@"Fluorine" elementsNumber:@"9"],
[Element elementsName:@"Neon" elementsNumber:@"10"],
```

I need to be able to access the elementsName and the elementsNumber separately.

Would anybody know how to do this, and is it possible? Thanks! (More code below!)

**Element.h (class for the array)**

```
@interface Element : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *number;
}

@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString *number;

+(id)elementsName:(NSString *)name elementsNumber:(NSString *)number;
```

**and Element.m**

```
#import "Element.h"

@implementation Element;
@synthesize number;
@synthesize name;

+(id)elementsName:(NSString *)name elementsNumber:(NSString *)number
{
    Element *newElement = [[self alloc] init];
    newElement.name = name;
    newElement.number = number;
    return newElement;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Comment: why don't you try to use array of NSDictionary instead of array with multiple property

Comment: Your syntax is off. Your constructor method should be named `elementWithName:(NSString *)name number:(NSNumber *)number`. Also, remove the `iVars` and `synthesize` as of Xcode 4.6 you no longer need them.

Comment: @Hayaßusa You could use dictionaries but sometimes it is nice to create custom classes. Especially if you want them to have actions, or lots of properties.

Comment: Element *element=(Element*)[mArray objectAtIndex:0];  use this line only to get values.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Aren't you just building a fixed set of the elements? You might be looking for a nice interface to an `Element` class that lets you access individual elements by name or number or all of them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<elementArray.count; i++)
{
    NSString *name = ((Element*)[elementArray objectAtIndex:i]).name;
    NSString *number = ((Element*)[elementArray objectAtIndex:i]).number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? :

```
// returns an array of all numbers
NSArray *numbers = [elementArray valueForKey:@"number"];

// returns an array of all names
NSArray *names = [elementArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

This is called KVC (Key-Value Coding) and uses strings to access an object's property. This example goes through all of the elements in the array and asks for its `number` or `name` property, then returns the result as an array.

This could also be achieved with a for-loop. I am mainly including this to give you an idea of what is happening:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Element *e in elementsArray) {
    [names addObject:e.name];
    [numbers addObject:e.number];
}
```

Obviously this would work as well, but why not use `valueForKey:` when it is designed for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDictionary instead.

```
NSArray *arrOfDic=@[@{@"elementsName":@"Lithium",@"elementsNumber":@"3"},
                    @{@"elementsName":@"Beryllium",@"elementsNumber":@"4"},
                    @{@"elementsName":@"Boron",@"elementsNumber":@"5"},
                    @{@"elementsName":@"Carbon",@"elementsNumber":@"6"},
                    @{@"elementsName":@"Nitrogen",@"elementsNumber":@"7"}];


NSLog(@"dic is %@",arrOfDic);
```

Get your elements and their number as

```
   NSLog(@"FirstObject is Element = %@ Element No = %@",arrOfDic[0][@"elementsName"],arrOfDic[0][@"elementsNumber"]);
    NSLog(@"SecondObject is Element = %@ Element No = %@",arrOfDic[1][@"elementsName"],arrOfDic[1][@"elementsNumber"]);
```

**And whats wrong with your file it is working fine.**

```
NSMutableArray *mArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[mArray addObject:[Element elementsName:@"Lithium" elementsNumber:@"3"]];
[mArray addObject:[Element elementsName:@"Beryllium" elementsNumber:@"5"]];
[mArray addObject:[Element elementsName:@"Boron" elementsNumber:@"6"]];

Element *element=(Element*)[mArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"My first element is name = %@ ,number = %@",element.name,element.number);
```

output---

**My first element is name = Lithium ,number = 3**